# How to stop sending asynchronous requests in Guzzle on certain condition?

Tags: php, guzzle6

When I catch many exceptions I want to stop sending requests in Guzzle. Does anybody know how can do that?

Here my snippet of code:

```
protected function parseAsyncCustomers($urls)
{
    $promises = (function () use ($urls) {
        do {
            $uri = new Uri(current($urls));
            $request = new Request('GET', $uri, ['User-Agent' => UserAgent::random()]);
            yield $this->httpClient->sendAsync($request, [
                'timeout' => 15,
                'connect_timeout' => 15,
            ]);
        } while (next($urls) !== false);
    })();

    (new \GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise($promises, [
        // Multiple Concurrent HTTP Requests
        'concurrency' => 10,
        'fulfilled' => function (ResponseInterface $response, $index) {
            $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
            $this->parseCustomerContent($content, $index);
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
            // This is delivered each failed request
            if ($reason instanceof GuzzleException) {                   
                if ($this->reject++ > 30) {
                    // how can stop sending next requests?
                }
            }
        },
    ]))->promise()->wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fourth parameter to the `rejected` callback which represents the whole `EachPromise`. You can reject it in your condition, and it will stop the execution flow.

```
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index, $idx, $aggregate) {
        // This is delivered each failed request
        if ($reason instanceof GuzzleException) {                   
            if ($this->reject++ > 30) {
                $aggregate->reject('Attempts limit exceeded')
            }
        }
    },
```